# CSS Unknown Margin/Padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a small project and I have encountered a problem. In the bgContainer class there are two bits of text and they have a margin between them, however I don't want any margin and I can't tell where the margin is coming from. According to chrome, the margin is 200px on the header text but, as far as I am aware, no where in my css have I set that to be the case. I'm also using bootstrap 4 beta 2. Any help appreciated, thanks.

[padding/margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPQjc.png)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
 overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Gotham, Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';
 font-weight: 200;
 font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.sidenav .sidebar-header {
 font-family: "Bebas Neue";
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.sidenav ul.components {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.sidenav ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.sidenav ul li a {
 color: #5C5C5C;
 text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: block;

}

.sidenav ul li a:hover {
    color: #5C5C5C;
    background: #fff;
 transform: scale(1.01);
}

.sidenav ul li.active {
 color: #e9ecef;
}

.sidenav ul li.current > a {
 color: #e9ecef;
 background-color: #5C5C5C;
}
ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #D0D0D0;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\f0d7';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
 right: 20px;
 top: 7px;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 0.8em;
 font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}

a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\f0d8';
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

.navButton {
 padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 20px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    margin: 3px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0px, 8px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0px, 8px) ;
}

.change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0px, -8px) ;
}
.bgConatiner {
 padding: 20px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 510px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.header {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.header p {
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 200px;
 font-family: "Bebas Neue";
 color: #FFF;
}
.subheader {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.subheader p {
 font-weight: 200;
 font-size: 100px;
 font-family: "Bebas Neue";
 color: #FFF;
}

.bg {
 width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
 background-image: url(../assets/header5.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: bottom;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="bg">
  <div id="mainSidenav" class="sidenav">
    <div class="sidebar-header">Solebooth</div>
    <!--Sidenav Menu-->
    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <li> <a href="#subNav1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Sneakers</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="subNav1">
          <li><a href="#">Adidas</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Asics</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#subNav2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Clothing</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="subNav2">
          <li><a href="#">Supreme</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bape</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Palace</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#subNav3" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Galley</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="subNav3">
          <li><a href="#">#1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">#2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">#3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top">
      <form>
        <div class="navButton" onclick="navButton(this)">
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </nav>
    <div class="bgConatiner">
      <div class="header">
        <p>SOLEBOOTH</p>
      </div>
      <div class="subheader">
        <p>Sneakers. Streetwear.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1"></div>
        <div class="col-10"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vestibulum, nunc sit amet egestas mollis, purus lorem rhoncus eros, sit amet molestie lectus nisl in augue. Morbi malesuada erat massa, eu aliquam risus tincidunt ut. Duis pellentesque vestibulum lacus. Nam sed tortor ullamcorper erat bibendum ullamcorper in in elit. Maecenas non est scelerisque, malesuada augue vitae, tristique diam. Maecenas luctus at ante in placerat. Suspendisse nec quam ornare ipsum vestibulum sodales in vitae lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vestibulum, nunc sit amet egestas mollis, purus lorem rhoncus eros, sit amet molestie lectus nisl in augue. Morbi malesuada erat massa, eu aliquam risus tincidunt ut. Duis pellentesque vestibulum lacus. Nam sed tortor ullamcorper erat bibendum ullamcorper in in elit. Maecenas non est scelerisque, malesuada augue vitae, tristique diam. Maecenas luctus at ante in placerat. Suspendisse nec quam ornare ipsum vestibulum sodales in vitae lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vestibulum, nunc sit amet egestas mollis, purus lorem rhoncus eros, sit amet molestie lectus nisl in augue. Morbi malesuada erat massa, eu aliquam risus tincidunt ut. Duis pellentesque vestibulum lacus. Nam sed tortor ullamcorper erat bibendum ullamcorper in in elit. Maecenas non est scelerisque, malesuada augue vitae, tristique diam. Maecenas luctus at ante in placerat. Suspendisse nec quam ornare ipsum vestibulum sodales in vitae lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vestibulum, nunc sit amet egestas mollis, purus lorem rhoncus eros, sit amet molestie lectus nisl in augue. Morbi malesuada erat massa, eu aliquam risus tincidunt ut. Duis pellentesque vestibulum lacus. Nam sed tortor ullamcorper erat bibendum ullamcorper in in elit. Maecenas non est scelerisque, malesuada augue vitae, tristique diam. Maecenas luctus at ante in placerat. Suspendisse nec quam ornare ipsum vestibulum sodales in vitae lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vestibulum, nunc sit amet egestas mollis, purus lorem rhoncus eros, sit amet molestie lectus nisl in augue. Morbi malesuada erat massa, eu aliquam risus tincidunt ut. Duis pellentesque vestibulum lacus. Nam sed tortor ullamcorper erat bibendum ullamcorper in in elit. Maecenas non est scelerisque, malesuada augue vitae, tristique diam. Maecenas luctus at ante in placerat. Suspendisse nec quam ornare ipsum vestibulum sodales in vitae lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vestibulum, nunc sit amet egestas mollis, purus lorem rhoncus eros, sit amet molestie lectus nisl in augue. Morbi malesuada erat massa, eu aliquam risus tincidunt ut. Duis pellentesque vestibulum lacus. Nam sed tortor ullamcorper erat bibendum ullamcorper in in elit. Maecenas non est scelerisque, malesuada augue vitae, tristique diam. Maecenas luctus at ante in placerat. Suspendisse nec quam ornare ipsum vestibulum sodales in vitae lacus. </div>
        <div class="col-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mainSidenav").style.width = "200px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "200px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mainSidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}

function navButton(x) {
  if(x.classList.contains("change")){
     closeNav();
     x.classList.remove("change");

  }else{
     openNav();
     x.classList.add("change");
  }
}
 </script> 
<!--JavaScript --> 
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/fdfcf3c386.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you upload an image of the result on your end?

Comment: Your question says bgContainer but your CSS and HTML both use bgConatiner. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply

```
.subheader p, .header p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

The reason why you see so much space around your `p`-s is that user-agent's (browser's) default styles are applied. For example, my browser (and yours as well, I suppose) applies:

```
p {
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
}
```

[Em](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)-s are relative to the font-size of the elements. Your `<p>`-s have font-sizes 100px and 200px. So, that's why you get those large margins. Also consider using things like [reset.css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to clear the user-agents' styles and reduce browser inconsistencies.